# Excel VBA Permission Denied Error

Tags: excel, vba

While I would like to run Macro on a xlsx, it prompts out

> Permission Denied

I already enabled all macro settings in trust center. How come?

Comment: How are you running it on the `xlsx`? If it's in the same workbook you'll lose all vba when saving. Also, check that the worksheet you're changing (if you're changing it) doesn't have any protection applied to it

Comment: use xlsm rather than xlsx

Comment: As above your first need to get this to Xlsm or Xlsb. Xlsx wont use Macros